# Vagrant shell provision command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant

I am using vagrant 1.6.2 and  using it with an ubuntu 14.04 box. When I do `vagrant provision` it runs an `.sh` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

apt-get update -qq
apt-get install -y make git-core

if [[ ! -d /home/vagrant/ansible ]]; then
    # Install Ansible dependencies.
    apt-get install -y python-mysqldb python-yaml python-jinja2 python-paramiko sshpass

    # Checkout the Ansible repository.
    git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git /home/vagrant/ansible

    mkdir /etc/ansible

    echo "localhost" > /etc/ansible/hosts

    source /home/vagrant/ansible/hacking/env-setup
    echo "source /home/vagrant/ansible/hacking/env-setup" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
fi

cd /home/vagrant/me/provisioning
ansible playbook.yml
```

But I get the message `/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 24: ansible: command not found`

But when I go into the box and type `ansible` it does work. 
How can I make it work through my `.sh` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the `source /home/vagrant/ansible/hacking/env-setup` directly in front of the `ansible playbook.yml` to ensure it is run every time before ansible is called.